# Display percentage on piechart in WPF

Tags: wpf, pie-chart

Hii

Can anyone tell me how can I show percentage on the piechart....
The percentage is seen on mouseover event but I dont know how to show
the percentage on the piechart's slices....

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to put labels on the chart itself (instead of tooltip), take a look at [this great blog post](http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=363) by WPF guru Bea Stollnitz.

It shows how to do this, in many different modes, and explains not only how, but why.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [amCharts Bundle for WPF](http://wpf.amcharts.com/pie). Pie chart supports labels on the slices, outside connected labels and includes an algorithm to prevent label overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

I've just followed [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/piechart11122009230249PM/piechart.aspx) (just to make sure) and I get the percentages of each slice as tooltip on mouse over by default.

If you post your code we might be able to spot if there's a problem with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use labelFunction in mx:PieSeries, and lableFunction look like that

```
private function pieSeries_labelFunc(item:Object, field:String, index:Number, percentValue:Number):String 
{
    return StringUtil.substitute("{0} ({1}%)",item.description,percentValue.toFixed(1));
}
```

Where description is the label that you want to see.
feel free to ask any question.